# Compiling binary with tensorflow library for cpu: Cannot find cuda library?

Tags: python, deployment, tensorflow, compilation, pyinstaller

In development, I have been using the gpu-accelerated tensorflow

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

I am attempting to deploy my trained model along with an application binary for my users. I compile using `PyInstaller (3.3.dev0+f0df2d2bb)` on python 3.5.2 to create my application into a binary for my users.

For deployment, I install the cpu version, https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

However, upon successful compilation, I run my program and receive the infamous tensorflow cuda error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:
>   tensorflow/contrib/util/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/_cudnn_rnn_ops.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**why is it looking for cuda when I've only got the cpu version installed?** (Let alone the fact that I'm still on my development machine with cuda, so it should find it anyway. I can use tensorflow-gpu/cuda fine in uncompiled scripts. But this is irrelevant because deployment machines won't have cuda)

My first thought was that somehow I'm importing the wrong tensorflow, but I've not only used `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` but then I also went to delete the tensorflow-gpu in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/

Any ideas what could be happening? Maybe I need to start using a virtual-env..

Comment: I came across this interesting issue that apparently only happens with compiled python. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12466. I guess a way to check whether this is what you are experiencing is to try compiling and running your code in a pristine docker that has never seen cuda.

Comment: Any progress on this? i'm facing the similar problem :S

Comment: @Tzomas Sorry, not yet! Been working on other things...